# Collatz sequence - Have I done it right?

Tags: python, collatz

I am now learning how to program in python and the book I am learning from gave me the practice project to build this sequence and place it in a loop until the value is 1.

My code looks like this:

```
print('Enter a number')
number = input()
num = number

def collatz(number):
    global num
    if int(num) % 2 == 0:
        num = int(num) // 2
        print(str(num))
    elif int(num) % 2 == 1:
        num = 3 * int(num) + 1
        print(str(num))
while num != 1:
    number = num
    collatz(number)
```

It works, but I am not sure if I've done it in the way I should've.
My issue was that I was using number both as a global variable and a parameter and when I first write the code every 'num' was called 'number', when first testing it it would enter an endless loop and repeat the first if or elif all over again. I figured that the problem is that it doesn't refer to the global variable but creates a local one, so I've tried to declare at the beginning to use the global one, as you can see, however it didn't let me as global variable and parameter can't be the same, so I've created the 'num' variable and assigned it to the if block, but now it looks like that the number parameter doesn't really interfere with my code.

The fact that it works makes me happy, however I would like to confirm this is right.

Comment: I would suggest codereview SO site for questions like this

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look, I only knew this site, as this is where I got help for VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I'd suggest you fix.

- No need for a separate `print` for `input`. Also might as well cast it to int now.

  `number = int(input('Enter a number'))`
- Get rid of the global and use `return`. Also get rid of your casting in your function.

See:

```
def collatz(n): # parameter is an int
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    print(n) # single print
    return n
```

So combined:

```
def collatz(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    print(n)
    return n
number = int(input('Enter a number'))
while number != 1:
    number = collatz(number)
```

Comment: I guess I would still need to replace the ‘number’ words with ‘n’s as number is not declared. Also, returning n would make the program store n, and therefore when I use it again that will have a new value?

Comment: so you passed `number` to your function but you never used it, you could change the parameter name to num and you'd have to change fewer things

Comment: What I mean is that in your code “combined” you used number and n both so I would have to change number = int(input..... to n = int(input....

Comment: Also thanks for the help, your code looks more efficient, I have used multiple lines because that’s how I learnt it, going forward I will go with your version